# Does Facebook allow users to sell pages?

Tags: facebook-pages

I've got a Facebook page with half a million likes, one that sort of exploded with likes without any action on my part. After hitting about 100k likes, I began to receive messages for offers to buy my page, and have been receiving them almost daily for about a year now.

Now, I realize 500k likes is pretty valuable. However, I'm not here to ask you about prices or whether I'm going to get screwed on it. I want to know:

Does Facebook allow users to sell pages?
How can I do that safely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Facebook does not allow to sell Facebook pages. It is a violation of Facebook **[terms](https://www.facebook.com/legal/terms)**. See the section 4, point 9:

> 4. **Registration and Account Security**
>
>    - You will not transfer your account (including any Page or application you administer) to anyone without first getting our written permission.

Comment: but I can with written permission? does that happen?

Comment: Yes, you need legal written permission for that from FB.

Comment: Do you know if that is common practice to contact FB to sell a page?

Comment: No, I do not have any idea about that.

Comment: Thanks, still relevant information though. I'm still getting tons of messages but I'd like to keep it legal :)